# Normal distribution for turtle at start

Tags: netlogo

I want to randomly place turtles within some x and y coordinates confines according to a Gaussian Distribution with no two turtles at the same patch.

Things I have tried:
1. There exists http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random-normal
but there how do I avoid turtles getting located same patch.

Previous code I used(only randomly distributed):

```
ask n-of population patches-in-box 
  [
    sprout-inboxturtles 1
]
```

;population- number of turtles
;patches-in-box -where i want to place turtles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in equivalent of [`n-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#min-one-of) for normal distributions (and it's not clear to me what it should be if there was one). So you'll have to use [`random-normal`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random-normal) and adapt it to your special case:

```
to distribute-turtles [ pop box ]
  if pop > count box [ error "Box can't hold all turtles!" ]
  let ys [ pycor ] of box
  let xs [ pxcor ] of box
  let min-x min xs
  let min-y min ys
  let max-x max xs
  let max-y max ys
  let mid-x mean list min-x max-x
  let mid-y mean list min-y max-y
  let w max-x - min-x
  let h max-y - min-y
  crt pop [
    loop [
      let x random-normal mid-x (w / 6)
      if x > max-x [ set x max-x ]
      if x < min-x [ set x min-x ]
      set xcor x
      let y random-normal mid-y (h / 6)
      if y > max-y [ set y max-y ]
      if y < min-y [ set y min-y ]
      set ycor y
      if not any? other turtles-here [ stop ]
    ]
    move-to patch-here ; to center in patch
  ]
end
```

And this is an example of how you would call it:

```
to setup
  ca
  let population 100
  let patches-in-box patches with [ abs pxcor < 10 and abs pycor < 10 ]
  ask patches-in-box [ set pcolor black + 2 ]
  distribute-turtles population patches-in-box
end
```

A few notes:

- The code would be more efficient if you passed it `min-x`, `max-x`, `min-y` and `max-y` directly instead of figuring out these values from the `box` agentset, but it should not make a huge difference unless your box is really big.
- We need to make sure that `pop` is less than the number of the patches, or it would loop forever because there would not be any free patch where to put the turtles: this is why we throw an error when it happens. And the closer `pop` is to `count box`, even if it gives no error, the longer it will take to complete because the last few turtles will have a hard time finding a spot.
- You can play with the standard deviations (`w / 6` and `h / 6`) to get the distribution shape you want (that's basically the "steepness" of the bell curve).
- `random-normal` is theoretically unbounded, so it could give you coordinates that are outside the box. This is why we "clip" the results to the min and max possible coordinates. If your standard deviations are too high, you may find that a lot of turtles end up "stuck" on the borders of the box.

Comment: Thanks! Work well. Though it is a bit inefficient when considering high population in less space.

Comment: See my other answer. You will need to download and install the [Rnd extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension), but it makes things much more efficient...

Answer (score 3):

I just realized that you can get around the speed problem completely by using the [`rnd:weighted-n-of`](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension#rndweighted-n-of-size-agentset-reporter-task) primitive of the NetLogo [Rnd Extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension)! Here is some revised code:

```
extensions [ rnd ]

to distribute-turtles [ pop box ]
  if pop > count box [ error "Box can't hold all turtles!" ]
  let ys [ pycor ] of box
  let xs [ pxcor ] of box
  let min-x min xs
  let min-y min ys
  let max-x max xs
  let max-y max ys
  let mid-x mean list min-x max-x
  let mid-y mean list min-y max-y
  let w max-x - min-x
  let h max-y - min-y
  ask rnd:weighted-n-of pop box [
    [ (p (pxcor - mid-x) (w / 6)) * (p (pycor - mid-y) (h / 6)) ] of ?
  ] [ sprout 1  ]
end

to-report p [ x std-dev ]
  report (1 / (std-dev * sqrt (2 * pi))) * e ^ (0 - ((x ^ 2) / (2 * (std-dev ^ 2))))
end
```

What [`rnd:weighted-n-of`](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension#rndweighted-n-of-size-agentset-reporter-task) does is that it takes an agentset (or a list) and a reporter task that should return a "weight" for each element. Elements with greater weights have better chances of being picked. In our case, we assign these weights to patches in the box using the [probability density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) of a [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) (that's the `p` reporter in the code).

You can use `distribute-turtles` in the same way as in my other answer:

```
to setup
  ca
  let patches-in-box patches with [ abs pxcor < 10 and abs pycor < 10 ]
  let population (count patches-in-box - 10)
  ask patches-in-box [ set pcolor black + 2 ]
  distribute-turtles population patches-in-box
end
```

...but in this case, the code runs very fast even if `population` is almost as big as `count patches-in-box`. Why? Because [`rnd:weighted-n-of`](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension#rndweighted-n-of-size-agentset-reporter-task) is "smart" enough to sometimes discard the elements that have already been picked and keep picking amongst only the ones that haven't been picked yet. (You can look at [the underlying Scala code](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension/blob/ee2dc5266338ce98c74d0ebf1679c9e1b95cb331/src/main/scala/org/nlogo/extensions/rnd/Picker.scala#L31) if you are interested in the details.) In our case, it means that patches near the center of the box won't get unsuccessfully picked over and over again: only the free spots will remain in play towards the end.